# Setting "Field Name" via Dropdown Instead of Textbox in PDFTron forms

Tags: javascript, pdftron, mendix

How can I implement a dropdown widget for setting the "Field Name" instead of a textbox in a custom PDF viewing solution using PDFTron within Mendix?
We have a backend-generated list of values that should populate the dropdown, allowing users to select a value as the field name.

In the image, we need to replace the text field by a drop down.

Despite researching the available resources and documentation, we haven't found a straightforward method to achieve this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the options of a dropdown listbox using WidgetAnnotation.options.

Please feel free to reach out to support at https://apryse.com/contact-us

Comment: Please post detailed answer and then references.